# Babel compile error on static class properties

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Babel with Webpack in a React demo. The compiling failed on static class properties with functions calls as object value. But fine with plain types.

```
ERROR in ./src/components/productSet.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/jack/demo/src/components/productSet.jsx: Unexpected token (9:35)
   7 |     static propTypes: {
   8 |         test: React.PropTypes.object,
>  9 |         data: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['News', 'Photos']),
     |                                    ^
  10 |     }
```

BTW, I've enable all 0-3 stage features

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-3', 'stage-2', 'stage-1', 'stage-0']
        }
    }]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `prototypes`, The `static prototypes` should be followed by `=` not `:`

try:

`static propTypes= {` instead of `static propTypes: {`

Comment: I have it right, but still getting similar error only on production releases, runs fine on dev builds.